# Synching data from dexie.js to the server via a server-side API

Tags: dexie

In my angular application, I want to get and save data from the server and store in the **IndexedDB** using Dexie.js. The data will be retrieved through a URL using [httpClient] [1](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

I did not see any API call in the documentation to make calls to the server. Should I make the calls outside of Dexie.js in the angular app to save or retrieve the data? Is there some type of hook where when the data is saved to the **IndexedDB**, the data also can be sent to the server using `fetch` or angular `httpClient`?

Comment: I did not solve it.